How can I create a std::string_view from integer literals/ ASCII code in a constexpr context?
GCC/ G++ supports the #embed directive also for C++ when activating GCC/ G++ extensions.
I would like to use this to populate a std::string_view constexpr from that.
#embed will create something like 65, 66, 67 from a string ABC to my understanding.
My problem is getting this into a variable.
If just using C, I would write something like:
const char test[] = {
#embed <blub.obj>
, 0};

, which would basically result in something like const char test[] = { 65, 66, 67, 0};.
However, I need this in C++ and to end in a constexpr std::string_view.
The ultimate goal is to create a frozen::unordered_map with several files where the std::string_view is parsed with a constexpr function before being put into it.
I tried a lot of variants, which made more or less sense to me, but the only one I found working was:
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

static constexpr std::array arr = std::to_array<char>({65, 66, 67});

static constexpr std::string_view sv(arr.data(), arr.size());

int main() {
    std::cout << sv << std::endl;
}

However, this has the drawback, that I basically need two constants for each constant.
Is there a one-liner which works at least with recent G++?
P.S.: Right now I create #define's from the CMakeLists.txt, which is not really nice.

static constexpr std::string_view my_constant_string{"abc"}; (or inline if you put the constants in a header file)

The problem on one foot is that any "temporary" you create to initialize the string view will end up invaliding the constexpr initialization. I'd just bite the bullet and do what works (naming conventions can hide the additional constant).

@PepijnKramer This is the normal initialization from a string literal, but #embed unfortunately gives me integer literals as I wrote in the question. :-(

How about create your own type wrapping std::array with operator std::string_view?

@Jarod42 Something like:
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct my_array : public std::array<T, N> {

    constexpr operator std::basic_string_view<T>() const {
        return std::string_view(this->data(), this->size());
    }
};

static constexpr std::string_view sv = my_array<char, 3>{65, 66, 67};

int main() {
    std::cout << sv << std::endl;
}

... is not a constant expression

I meant that, i.e using only variable as array, and let deduction to string_view happens when needed. So indeed might failed with template method.
